# Get the last line of a specific function in a .ps1 file

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to get the last line of a specific function in a .ps1 file. I already accomplished this with powershell v3 code:

```
function GetEndLineNumber($ParseFile, $functionName))
{
    $AbstractSyntaxTree = $NewParser::ParseFile($ParseFile, [ref]$null,  [ref]$null)
    $functionsInFile = $AbstractSyntaxTree.FindAll({$args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst]}, $true)
    #endregion

    $initializeFunction = $null
    foreach($function in $functionsInFile)
    {
        if($function.Name -eq $functionName)
        {
            $initializeFunction = $function
            break
        }
    }

    if($initializeFunction -eq $null){ return 0 }

    $initializeFunctionBody = $initializeFunction.Body

    return $initializeFunctionBody.Extent.EndLineNumber
}
```

But this script should also run on v2, i tried with System.Management.Language.PSParser and with ScriptBlock. But without any success. Someone knows how I could get the last line ( as an int or string) of a specific function name in a .ps1 file?

### EDIT:

I think here are some missunderstandings:
I want to get the last line of a specific function in a .ps1 script. Not the last line of a specific function in a function. Because I have to add my own code to this function at the end
Here a simple example how my script could look:

#### test.ps1

```
1function test321
2 {
3  Write-Host "test3142"
4 }
5
6function test1
7{
8 if($true)
9 {
10  Write-Host "hello"
11 }
12 #comment
13 
14 Write-host "end"
15 
16}
17
18function test2
19{
20 #bla
21}
```

I want a function called e.g. like GetEndLineNumber($scriptFile, $functionName) and it should be work like this:

#### test2.ps1

```
$path = "C:\Scripts\test.ps1"
$lastLine = GetEndLineNumber $path "test1"

$lastLine should be in this case 15 or 16.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PowerShell V2 we can use `System.Management.Automation.PSParser` and do some
parsing ourselves using produced tokens:

```
function GetEndLineNumber {
    param(
        $scriptFile,
        $functionName
    )

    $code = Get-Content -LiteralPath $scriptFile
    $tokens = [System.Management.Automation.PSParser]::Tokenize($code, [ref]$null)

    $waitForFuncName = $false
    $funcFound = $false
    $level = 0

    foreach($t in $tokens) {
        switch($t.Type) {
            Keyword {
                if ($t.Content -eq 'function') {
                    $waitForFuncName = $true
                }
            }
            CommandArgument {
                if ($waitForFuncName) {
                    $waitForFuncName = $false
                    $funcFound = $t.Content -eq $functionName
                }
            }
            GroupStart {
                ++$level
            }
            GroupEnd {
                --$level
                if ($funcFound -and $level -eq 0 -and $t.Content -eq '}') {
                    return $t.StartLine
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did not test it thoroughly but I tried it for a few functions and scripts and it
returned correct line numbers.

Comment: This is what I had in mind, but doesn't correctly handle the tricky case mentioned in my answer.

Comment: In this case you may up-vote the answer because it has this tricky case done.

Comment: Indeed, it does look right - I guess I didn't read the code closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

In V3, there is another a simpler option for functions that already exist:

```
$cmd = Get-Command -Name $functionName -CommandType Function,Filter
if ($null -ne $cmd)
{
    return $cmd.ScriptBlock.Ast.Extent.EndLineNumber
}
```

This will work for functions defined with the function/filter keywords as well as with Set-Item, e.g.

```
Set-Item -Path function:foo -Value { return 42 }
```

The original code using the Parser api wouldn't work correctly in this case.

In V2, the PSParser api might be the best alternative - but it would require some slightly tricky parsing.  After you find the 'function' token followed by the function name you want, you would skip the optional parameter list (matching '(' and ')') and then you would match '{' and '}' tokens, the last unnested '}' token being your last line.

This isn't complicated code, but it's a little tricky, e.g. if you didn't skip the optional parameter list, you could incorrectly find matched curly braces as a default argument, e.g.

```
function foo($a = {}) {}
```

Comment: Could you give me a code snippet? Because I think, it is complicated. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this way of getting last line :

First .source the PS1 file :

```
. .\Myscript.ps1
```

Then get the scriptblock of the function :

```
$myFunction = Get-Item Function:\MyFunction
($myFunction.ScriptBlock ).ToString().split("`n") | select -last 1
```

As you can read in @mjolinor's answer you should be carreful in that split.

Comment: I do not want to get the content of the last line in the function. I want to get the number of the last line in this function. But if the .ps1 has 105, and the function 20 and the function is in the middle. The return value should be something like 48 and not 19.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your question, Perhaps you can try with regular expressions, or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) but I do not found the PowerShell grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @JPBlanc's answer, be careful with that split.  It appears to count everything between the curly braces as part of the script block, including any newlines immediately before and after:

```
 function test {
 'line1'
 'line2'
 'line3'
 }

 $myFunction = Get-Item Function:\test
 ($myFunction.ScriptBlock ).ToString().split("`n").count

 5


 function test {'line1'
 'line2'
 'line3'}

 $myFunction = Get-Item Function:\test
 ($myFunction.ScriptBlock ).ToString().split("`n").count

 3
```

Taking the last element of the split from that first one returns a blank line. 
Just to be safe, I'd run it through .trim() before you do the split.  You can also shorten it some by using `$function:<function name>` instead of `Get-Item`, and array slicing instead of `-Select` :

```
function test {
'line1'
'line2'
'line3'
}

$function:test.tostring().trim().split("`n")[-1]

'line3'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've updated the question, i hope that its clearer now.